# restricted-extras available in ubuntu 12.10 demo version

Tags: installation, rhythmbox

i'm new to ubuntu. before installing, i wanted to try it first. but, whenever i want to play media files using rhythmbox, it says "python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder". 
i searched a bit on the net, and for that i'm required to install restricted-extras.
but there's no option of "install" in Ubuntu software center.
when i tried through terminal it said, "E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras".
currently, i'm using ubuntu through bootable usb.
so, is the restricted-extras package not available in demo version??? i need to install ubuntu to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to ubuntu software centre and install unrestricted extras. thats it..

Comment: that's the problem. there's no "install" option. i haven't installed ubuntu yet. i'm just currently using its "try now" option. that's why, i'm asking, are restricted-extras not available for demo versions??? or is there something wrong?

Comment: yeah sometimes its happens even after installing it on HDD, but it can be easily resolved by rebooting your system, faced the same issue with completely installed ubuntu and resolved by rebooting.. 

well in ur case as u haven't installed it you can not reboot it for changes and yes its certain to have such issues ..for understanding your problem i have checked by using try ubuntu on other system and there too its same i cant install anything from ubuntu software center. that means there nothing wrong with your system or installation . its obvious ....

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses several repositories and even ppa to package programs.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

As with an installation, all these packages are available when running a live CD/USB. The "problemes" you might have are that anything you install will be lost when you reboot and you might run out of space if you install a lot of packages or update.

To install restricted extras , see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

There is even a link you simply click to install

> If you are using regular, stock Ubuntu: Click here to install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package